# Facebook custom graph action not appearing

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I found a very similar question here: [Actions do not appear on timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669492/actions-do-not-appear-on-timeline), but the solutions offered there are not working for me.

I created a custom graph action and a custom graph object through my Facebook application, and the process of publishing seems to be working fine. When I post the data using the JavaScript SDK with my access token and the object ID, the Facebook API returns the ID of the action, which I can then access on the graph. This side of things is clearly working, since accessing the object via the graph with my app's access token returns all the information it is supposed to.

However, I see no record of this action on Facebook itself; not on my app's timeline, not on the aggregation I set up for this action. The solutions offered in the link above entail double-checking the validity of the meta tags, which I did using the debugger, and also ensuring that there are no URLs within the meta tags that are inaccessible, which is also not the case. Is there anything else that could prevent these actions from showing up on the timeline?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There can be some permission error for facebook (and thus global users) for some url. If you get the action response id, it has to be in your facebook timeline at least (not in others excluding the developers and testers of your app) and it really occurs almost real time.

PS: If you found a similar questions elsewhere, please try to go on with the discussion there instead of creating a duplicate question.